# Regarding a formula for the function in the excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a problem with calculating in cell like this is shown here:

[image: Excel problem]

now I wanted to use a formula for it using Product function

I have written it as PRODUCT(C33:G33)*(0.3+0.6)/2
Now the problem is I don't want to write *(0.3+0.6)/2 in the formula it has to take that from the cell and calculate
can anyone provide a formula for it

Comment: So put in cell A1 "=(0.3+0.6)/2" then use PRODUCT(C33:G33)*A$1 or PRODUCT(C33:G33,A$1)

Answer (score 0):

This solution would require to format your file as macro enabled workbook. Create a simple *UDF* in `VBA`:

```
Function TextToFormula(text As String)
TextToFormula = Evaluate(text)
End Function
```

Use this *UDF* to convert text in cell to formula (let's say is id in `H3`):

```
=PRODUCT(C33:G33)*TextToFormula(H3)
```

Or write formula `=(0.3+0.6)/2` in `A1` and then formula `=PRODUCT(C33:G33)*A1`

Use `=SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"=","")` in `A2` if you want to "show" calculation steps somewhere:

[image]